# Trouble with using lua function as a condition

Tags: lua

I am refactoring a lua wireshark dissector and I am having trouble with using a function as the conditional.

this works:

```
-- define heuristic 
local function protocol_heuristic(buffer, packet, parent)

   -- min header length required
    if buffer:len() < 23 then
        return false
    end
```

this does not:

```
-- verify header
local function valid_packet_length(buffer)
    if buffer:len() > 23 then
        return true
    end

    return false
end

-- define heuristic 
local function protocol_heuristic(buffer, packet, parent)

    -- min header length required
    if not valid_packet_length(buffer) then
        return false
    end
```

I have tried 'not', == true and a few other iterations.  Being able to clean code the methods would be very helpful as it makes the source more generic and therefore much easier to auto generate.  The condition works inside the local function so there is either a syntax error or I do not understand the nature of lua functions and return values.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Something that works:

```
local is_valid_packet_length = valid_packet_length(buffer) 
if not is_valid_packet_length then return false end
```

Comment: The negation of `buffer:len() < 23` is `buffer:len() >= 23`. Perhaps your buffer has lenght 23...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look but the issue is not with the Boolean logic. Rather my lack of knowledge of lua.  one thing that does work is:   'local is_valid_packet_length = valid_packet_length(buffer)
    if not is_valid_packet_length then return false end'

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My attempts to assemble what you posted into a small Lua test script, worked as expected. Unfortunately I can't post that as an answer as technically it isn't answering the question, it is exploring your problem. Please edit your question to do that.